# How to solve $3 + 0.075x = 1.075^x$ for x?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I tried various methods... Could only solve it numerically not analytically. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try Lambert W?

Comment: @Alon: Closed form: $x = W_n((483570327845851669882470400000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (3 \log(2)+\log(5)-\log(43)))/654424391576726609728845810638511030159912807891585342916136964003)+40 \log(43)-40 \log(5)-120 \log(2))/(3 \log(2)+\log(5)-\log(43)),   n\ \in Z$ $${}$$ Numerically, we have $$x = -39.2181, x = 21.0335$$

Comment: Then without "=" please!

Comment: Sorry I do not know the Lambert W function.. I will look it up

Comment: I can't solve it in short time but [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3+%2B+0.075x+%3D+1.075%5Ex) can

Answer (score 3):

The equation
$$a+b x=c^x$$ has solutions in terms of Lambert function. It is given by
$$x=-\frac{1}{\log (c)}W\left(-\frac{\log (c) }{b}c^{-\frac{a}{b}}\right)-\frac{a}{b}$$ but this function has multiple branches.

Consider that you look for the zero's of $$f(x)=c^x-bx-a$$ which has as derivatives
$$f'(x)=c^x \log (c)-b\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=c^x \log ^2(c)\, \, >0 \, \forall x$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{\log \left(\frac{b}{\log (c)}\right)}{\log (c)}$$ which is aminimum. So, if $f(x_*)<0$ tow possible roots. If you want to approximate them, develop as Taylor series aound this point 
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac{1}{2} (x-x_*)^2 f''(x_*)+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ and solve the quadratic to get as *estimates*
$$x_\pm=x_* \pm \sqrt{-2\frac{f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$

Applied to your case, this would give $x_-=-26.6577$ and $x_+=27.6638$; using them as starting values, Newton method would converge very fast to the solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it with MatDeck as well, the equations solutions are -39.218 and 21.033

[Solving of nonlinear equations in MatDeck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQTYK.png)